# To how many odd keystones can one Spiritomb be synchronized?

Tags: pokemon-tabletop-united

Spiritombs have the "Keystone Warp" capability, which says the following:

> Spiritomb carries around with it an
> Odd Keystone. Trainers may collect additional Odd
> Keystones as they travel. They may then synchronize
> them with a Spiritomb for the cost of 2 Tutor Points.
> A Spiritomb may then freely teleport between any Odd
> Keystones within 10 meters as a Standard Action.

Do these 2 tutor points need to be paid for each individual Odd Keystone? Or is this a total price that allows a trainer to synchronize any amount of Odd Keystones that they have managed to gather with their Spiritomb?